# Show calculation result instead of a input

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to see the result of the calculation in the INPUTS tab, instead of being able to add an input.

Example: I add a value for Input 1 and the result for Input 2 is (Input 1 * 2). I want to show this reult in INPUTS tab.

I would like to see the result in the INPUTS tab.

```
//Lets say Input 1 is:
L1_02 = input(true, title="Line 1 Base" )
Line1_02 = input(10.0, title=" ")

//I want Line2_02 to be the result found in calculation from Band2_02
L2_02 = input(true, title="Line 2 - Multiplier" )
Line2_02 = input(Band2_02) //this gives me Syntax error.

//Calculation for Line2_02
Band2_02 = Line1_02 * 2
//The result would be 10*2 = 20.
```

How do I make an Input to get the value from an calculation?
Or what is it called so I can search for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables inside inputs or use the input tab to display data. Input types are meant to be constants and not the same data type as normal time series variables. In the case of `Line1_02` it is a constant `input.float` type not `float` and not meant to change or be altered. If you want to display data it's best to use the label or table functions. eg

```
info_label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = tostring(Band2_02))
label.delete(info_label[1]
```